# JSF 2.0 AJAX call not working for third commandlink onwards

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have the following code that uses AJAX to pop up a box when clicked. I cannot understand why only the first two items work but links 3 onwards do not. In debugger, I observed that clicking on first or second item triggers the breakpoint specified in listener but clicking on third item or higher does not. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

```
<ui:repeat var="lrhid" value="#{fn:split(lrrItem.lrHeaderId, ',')}" varStatus="loop" rendered="#{fn:length(lrrItem.lrHeaderId)>1}">
<h:commandLink id="xlrhid" value="#{lrhid}" onclick="ShowContent('xlrdetail1');">
    <c:set var="lrhparts" value="#{fn:split(lrhid,'-')}" />
    <f:param name="strlrhid" value="#{lrhparts[0]}"></f:param>
    <f:param name="strlrdseq" value="#{lrhparts[1]}"></f:param>
    <f:ajax execute="xlrhid" event="action" render=":leaveRequestReportForm:lrdetail" listener="#{lRViewDtlMB.getLeaveRecord}" />
</h:commandLink>&nbsp;
</ui:repeat>
```

Code for pop-up xlrdetail1:

```
<h:panelGroup id="xlrdetail1"  style="z-index:999;display:none;position:absolute;background-color: white;padding: 5px;">
<h:panelGroup id="lrdetail">
<ui:include src="lrViewById.xhtml"></ui:include>
<a onmouseover="HideContent('xlrdetail1'); return true;"
href="javascript:HideContent('xlrdetail1')">
[hide]</a>
</h:panelGroup>                 
</h:panelGroup>
```